# How to download image in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to download an image from my angular application. Image is stored in my backend server. Whenever i'm try to download it using following method i'm not able to download image but i'm being redirected to new page which opens up my image(like open image in new tab).

```
onDownloadQRCode(){
    // this.uploaded_table_qrcode has url of image i'm trying to download
    const a: any = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this.uploaded_table_qrcode;
    a.download = 'rest';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this stuff in Iframe may be it works
i think you stuck at CORS property

Comment: It's not due to cors property. Because i'm able to view image in application and download it using save images by right clicking it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).